# Query Rewrite Template in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Oracle SQL Query as below :

```
select id from docs where CONTAINS (text,
 '<query>
   <textquery lang="ENGLISH" grammar="CONTEXT"> Informix
     <progression>
       <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", "AND"))</rewrite></seq>
     </progression>
   </textquery>
</query>')>0;
```

The Query Works as expected. But I want to search for word Inform / Infor / Info. So I altered the query to below :

```
select id from docs where CONTAINS (text,
 '<query>
   <textquery lang="ENGLISH" grammar="CONTEXT"> Informix
     <progression>
       <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "?{", "}", "AND"))</rewrite></seq>
     </progression>
   </textquery>
</query>')>0;
```

By adding extra "?" in transform function. But this looks for informix / informi / inform / infor / info / inf / in. I want to restrict the search to a specific characters 4. Say till info. How can the same be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: You search string was informix in first place and then kukui nut??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all documents that contain at least one occurrence of any of the terms between informix and info use the OR operator
and list all you allowerd terms in the template

```
 <query>
    <textquery lang="ENGLISH" grammar="CONTEXT"> informix informi inform infor info
      <progression>
        <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", "OR"))</rewrite></seq>
      </progression>
    </textquery>
 </query>
```

But the usage of template is not realy meaninfull here.
The same result you get with a direct query

```
 select score(1), id from docs
 where    contains(text,'informix OR informi OR inform OR infor OR info',1) > 0
 order by 1 desc;
```

The advantage of this case is that you can controll the score by prefering the documents with longer string with higher [weights](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqoper.htm#i998379)

```
 select score(1), id from docs
 where    contains(text,'informix*5 OR informi*4 OR inform*3 OR infor*2 OR info',1) > 0
 order by 1 desc;
```

Btw the ? [(fuzzy)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqoper.htm#i997330) operator is used IMO to find misspelled words, not the exact prefixes of a term.

**UPDATE**

The concatenation of the prefixes you may assembly in PL/SQL or if necessary in SQL such as follows:

```
 with txt as (     
 select 'informix' text from dual),
 txt2 as (
 select 
  substr(text,1,length(text) -rownum+1) text
 from txt connect by level <= length(text) -3
 )
 select 
   LISTAGG( text, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY  text desc)
 from txt2
```

.

```
 informix, informi, inform, infor, info
```

Comment: Thanks Marmite for the explanation.

Comment: My Input is "informix". How do i frame that dynamically every-time to "informix informi inform infor info". Input may be any string.